# How to enable version in SharePoint using lists.xml?

Tags: list, version-control, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I want to enable version in list using list.xml. I tried some ways but it did not work. Can you please help me on how can I make it work ?

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" 
Title="Departments" 
FolderCreation="FALSE" 
Direction="$Resources:Direction;" 
Url="Lists/Departments" 
VersioningEnabled="TRUE" 
EnableMajorVersions="TRUE" 
MajorVersionLimit="5" 
MajorWithMinorVersionLimit="5" 
BaseType="0" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
```

[image]

Comment: From this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/list-element-list?redirectedfrom=MSDN#attributes

It is written, on the line where VersioningEnabled is:
"Optional Boolean. TRUE to specify within a Schema.xml file that versioning be enabled by default for document libraries created through the list definition. Setting this attribute has no effect on existing document libraries. **If TRUE, versioning can still be disabled for a document library on the New Document Library page when the library is being created.**"

Comment: There is a workaround in this link : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b5f6da89-2c91-47de-97bc-3319449dd1d4/versioningenabled-in-the-schemaxml-file?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

"**Instead I suggest you save a document library which has enabled versioning as a template then you can use this template when you create a new document library. By doing that the newly created document library will have versioning enabled automatically.**"